# Orchard and jQuery client template binding

Tags: jquery, orchardcms

Can anybody point me to any documentation/examples of Orchard views involving jQuery client template binding. I cannot get my code to work. I am pasting some parts of code below.

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    Script.Include("jquery.tmpl.min.js").AtHead();   
}
<fieldset>
        <!--Template Container-->
        <div id="myContainer"></div>

        <!--ViewModel Template-->
        <script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
            <div>
                {{= Prop1}}<br />
                {{= Prop2}}
            </div>
        </script>
</fieldset>


    @using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">      
        $(document).ready(function () {            

                //some JS code for Ajax to work

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                }).done(function (data) {      
                    alert("success"); //GETS TILL HERE          
                    $("#myTemplate").render(data).appendTo("#myContainer");
                });  
        }); 
    </script>
}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Did you inspect the console to see if any errors occur?

Comment: When you attach the browser's debugger, does the "data" object contain the expected values?

Comment: If you setup an isolated MVC project, does it work then?

Comment: @Spike. Thanks for the reply. Your tips (tip#1) helped me debug this issue and finally resolve it. However it is decided now we wont be using client templates since its not officially supported. Thanks again. Please put your comments in a post so that I can mark them as answers.

Comment: Glad to hear it, but too bad you can't use client templates. Are you using something else maybe?

Comment: No actually. we will handling everything in the Controller (server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to check and try:

1. Did you inspect the console to see if any errors occur?
2. When you attach the browser's debugger, does the "data" object contain the expected values?
3. If you setup an isolated MVC project, does it work then?